# SObject type offer__c is not supported by this unit of work

Tags: apex, error, dml, fflib

In the project, we use fflib as the Apex enterprise framework.
Executing this code:

> uow.registerDirty(offers);
>
> > uow.commitWork();

I get this error:   **The object type offer__c is not supported by this work unit**.
We use several Custom Objects which I do not receive any error from fflib. Instead, this particular one does.
What could it be?

Answer (score 2):

Problem resolved. Working with several Application Classes, the Offer__c object was defined in another Application Class instead of the one defined as uow.